# How to download the SDK binary files from cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, cocoapods, webrtc

I m not under XCode, but under Delphi and I want to integrate WebRTC in my project. The doc says to use Cocoapods by adding the following lines to my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'YOUR_APPLICATION_TARGET_NAME_HERE' do
  platform :ios, '9.0'
  pod 'GoogleWebRTC'
end
```

and the library is here: https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleWebRTC

But I can't do this in Delphi. I just need the binary file and I will install it myself in my project. How can I retrieve the binary of the library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the Podspec link on the right margin of https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleWebRTC. The download location is in the podspec:

> ```
> "http": "https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/ef02db06029b324a/GoogleWebRTC-1.1.25821.tar.gz"
> ```